# Why does Jenkins calls getLastSuccessfulBuild consider unstable to be succesfull when there's a call for getLastUnstableBuild

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Can someone tell me how I'd find last green build for jenkins 2.277?

After upgrading I found a behavior change where `getLastSuccessfulBuild()` returns the same value as `getLastUnstableBuild()`

Which means, when I promote, I can't trust these functions and need to write something to walk back through builds checking status.

In the scenario below:

- 6 = unstable
- 5 = successful / green
- 4 = failed / red

```
last                Experiments/exp.Stability #6
last successful     Experiments/exp.Stability #6
last unstable       Experiments/exp.Stability #6
last failed         Experiments/exp.Stability #4
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the last "green" build `getLastStableBuild()` needs to be used